# Ignore subfolders of URI in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have an app where you can send a link to content. The link is build like this:
`domain.com/share/param1/param2/param3`
The app is opened if the user has the app installed, otherwise it will open the website. For those who have not the app installed I got a webpage at `domain.com/share` where links to download the app are placed. The problem is that if you call `/ share/.../.../...` you don't get redirected to `/share`.

I want to redirect everything with `/share/...` beginning to `/share`

I'm running Wordpress on an Apache

What I tried:

```
RewriteEnginge On

#1
RewriteRule ^share/.*$ share

#2
RewriteRule ^share/(.*)$ share

#3
RewriteRule ^share\/(.*)$ share

#4
RewriteRule share/.* share

#5 this is to exclude an error to Regex
RewriteRule share/test share
```

The rest of the `.htaccess` which (hopefully) doesn't have an impact:

```
# BEGIN Thunermay (Admin)
# set apple-app-site-association as application/json for Apple's crawler

<Files "apple-app-site-association">
    Header set Content-type 'application/json'
</Files>

# ensure https

RewriteEngine On

# redirect all /share/anything links to /share
# Here was I trying to get it to work #

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

# END Thunermay

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"which (hopefully) doesn't have an impact"_ - that will depend on where exactly you put your attempts? They would need to come at least before the WordPress block, because in there everything that doesn't match a physically existing file or folder, will be rewritten to the index.php, and rewriting stops at that point.

Comment: @CBroe Yes it was before that, where the comment is. What exactly says that everything is redirected if there is not a folder?

Comment: The RewriteConds checking whether %{REQUEST_FILENAME} is not a file or a folder, only if those are fulfilled, the following RewriteRule gets applied.

Comment: Do you want only an internal rewrite here, or an actual external redirect? For the latter, you'd need to put the `R` flag on your attempts, otherwise it will only rewrite internally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, as @Cbroe stated, that I didn't redirect to the page but would only internally redirect, where the problem is, that this site does not exist. The solution was:
`RewriteRule /share/.+ share [R,L]`
The `+` is to have at least one character because otherwise it ended in an infinite loop, the `R` is to redirect it and not only show it in the URI and the `L` is for that it is the last rule and Wordpress does not catch it and point to the landing page.

The slight problem remaining is that my https redirect does not work anymore **IF** I have a share link and use `http` which my URI-generator does not, so it should not be an problem.